# How to remove a portion of an element?

Tags: html, css

Here's how I do it:

```
<style>
  #myElement {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
      border-radius: 50%;
  }

  #myElement::after {
      content: 'Some Text';
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: white; /*the same color as the background*/
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uw59ye26/

But what if there is a background image?

```
<style>
  html {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 255, 68), rgb(186, 255, 157));
  }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqva1are/

Comment: do you want to remove the background image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper to the element and give it a lesser height and add `overflow: hidden`

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 255, 68), rgb(186, 255, 157));
}
.test {
    height: 100px; overflow: hidden;
}
#myElement {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><div id="myElement"></div></div>
```